# When I wrap a doParallel I get Error in { : task 1 failed - "subscript out of bounds"

Tags: r, doparallel

I am trying to perform a Best Subset Selection regression using the Dirlich regression model. Here is some simulated data.

```
library(doParallel)
library(DirichletReg)

OpA<-runif(1000,0,0.25)
OpB<-runif(1000,0,0.25)
OpC<-1-OpA-OpB

V1<-runif(1000,0,1.0)
V2<-runif(1000,0,1.0)
V3<-runif(1000,0,1.0)
V4<-runif(1000,0,1.0)
V5<-runif(1000,0,1.0)

data.df<-data.frame(cbind(OpA,OpB,OpC,V1,V2,V3,V4,V5))

AL <- DR_data(data.df[, c("OpA","OpB","OpC")])
cnames<-c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5")
```

I want to get the log liklehood from all: one variable; all two variables; etc models:

```
l<-1
results.df<-data.frame(fn=character(),
                       logLik=double())
results.df$fn<-as.character(results.df$fn)
for (i in seq(1,length(cnames))){
  models<-(t(combn(cnames,i)))
  for (j in seq(1:nrow(models))){
    fn<-"AL~1"
    for(k in 1:i)
      fn<-paste(fn,models[j,k],sep="+")
    DR.Fit <- DirichReg(formula(fn), data.df)
    results.df[l,]$fn<-fn
    results.df[l,]$logLik<-DR.Fit$logLik
    l<-l+1
  }
}
```

The data frame `results.df` gives me the answer. However in reality I will need to run this for a larger candidate set of variables and on repeated sub sets of the data. I am thus trying to parallelise the problem. My intention is that inside the parallel loop a different random sub-set of the data will be selected for training (estimation) and the remainder used for testing (prediction). Here is the parallel wrapper:

```
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)

fn<-character()
clusterExport(cl, c("AL","fn"))
p<-foreach(p=1:4,
           .combine = combine, 
           .multicombine = TRUE,
           .packages=c("DirichletReg"))%dopar%{

  l<-1
  results.df<-data.frame(fn=character(),
                         logLik=double())
  results.df$fn<-as.character(results.df$fn)
  for (i in seq(1,length(cnames))){
    models<-(t(combn(cnames,i)))
    for (j in seq(1:nrow(models))){
      fn<-"AL~1"
      for(k in 1:i)
        fn<-paste(fn,models[j,k],sep="+")
      DR.Fit <- DirichReg(formula(fn), data.df)
      results.df[l,]$fn<-fn
      results.df[l,]$logLik<-DR.Fit$logLik
      l<-l+1
    }
  }
  return(results.df)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

I have done nothing more than repeat the same models four times here, looking for `p` to contain some duplicate results - all OK at this stage. However when I run this I get

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "subscript out of bounds"
```

How can I debug this process to work out what is causing this issue?

As an aside I don't know why I needed to predefine `fn`, and then clusterExport this along with `AL`, it should of been created in each cluster?